# Cart Price Rule - Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.2, magento2.4

I am using Magento 2.4, I am creating Cart Price Rule for conditional free shipping. I am not using any Tax in my website. I am just adding condition in Subtotal, If cart subtotal is greater than AED350 than Free shipping should be display auto on checkout page else not.

But after adding this condition I have amount AED200 in my cart. But That shipping method is still displaying. Please check attached file.

Thanks & Regards

[image]

Comment: This is not the way you set a free shipping. In this condition you basically say that IF subtotal is eq or greater than 350 AND shipping method is Free shipping THEN apply the cart rule. So, for a free shipping method based on cart amount, you can set the TABLERATES method or enable the free shipping method and set a threshold.

Comment: I have multiple free shipping for multiple countries with different threshold, how to I can define multiple free shipping and express shipping according to that country ? Please help if you can.